# How to speed up queries for raster databases?

Tags: postgis, raster, query, performance, spatial-index

I have a raster database in postgresql/postgis with these columns:

**(ID, rast, data_of_data)**.

**'rast'** is the column that has raster files in WKT format. An example query to find the DN value of a point in WGS84 system (30.424, -1.66) and for 2002-01-09 is the following:

```sql
SELECT 
     st_value(rast,(st_GeomFromText('POINT(30.424 -1.66)', 4326))) as val
FROM 
     my_table
WHERE
     date_of_data='2002-01-09'
```

**Is there a method (eg. spatial index) to speed up those kind of queries?**

Comment: Perhaps you could help us out by providing some more details: How many records are in my_table? How big is the data in the raster column? How many distinct dates do you have in date_of_data?

Comment: Add to this: what is the SRID of the rast column?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an exciting question! How big is the raster you want to query? WKTRaster is stored in the database [as a BLOB](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRaster/Documentation01). In order to find the value at a specific point, from a known (x_0, y_0) corner coordinate row/column indices (i, j) are computed using (dx, dy) steps and rotation. With (i, j) known, the ST_Value() function can access the actual data at the correct byte offset.

This means that the DB has to read on average at least half of the data blob when answering a query for a point (depending on the implementation it may actually read all of the data at all times). I would therefore *guess* that WKTRaster performance suffers when the data BLOBs get too large. Tiling the dataset should speed up queries. Have a look at how SRTM data (coming in 6000x6000 pixel chunks) is handled in [this tutorial](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRasterTutorial01). They actually tile the data into really small 50x50 pixels, which is a clear hint that my guessing may be not too far from the truth.

Spatially indexing raster data will probably just index the bounding box, which is no real help for your problem.

Comment: The tiling thing seems to be the way to go - see [this link](http://postgis.17.n6.nabble.com/raster-loading-and-ST-Value-performance-td4999924.html). You'll also need to add an index like this: `CREATE INDEX srtm_tiled_rast_gist_idx  ON srtm_tiled USING GIST (ST_ConvexHull(rast));` ([source](http://postgis.17.n6.nabble.com/Retrieving-Data-from-PostGIS-Raster-using-ST-Value-td3551194.html))

Answer (score 6):

Two aspects that I found sped up my PostGIS raster calculations, were using integer values in the raster, and using multi-band rasters where possible. In this case, can the DN value be stored as integers, if this is not already being done?

The other thought (and I'm not certain it is relevant here) is to use multi-band rasters. For example, if you are looking at monthly slices of data, each month could be a raster layer. Then you can retrieve multiple values of a point at different time slices by querying the layered raster. I found this approach to be much quicker than querying separate rasters.

Finally, when you load your data there is the `-t` flag for [TILE_SIZE](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/using_raster.xml.html#RT_Raster_Loader). You could explore if the tile size that you are using works well for your query.

Comment: Multiband rasters will likely help if you need to query the same pixel's value for *several months at the same time* (to stick with your example), e.g. to analyse time series. The query in the question only retrieves one specific date. If the date was contained in one band, the DBMS would need to read all the other bands as well, even though they are of no interest for answering the query. This would probably deteriorate performance.

Comment: I agree - perhaps I did not emphasize that it is only useful if several values are needed at the same time; I'll clarify this.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the distribution of your data, you might get some very good speedups just by indexing the `date_of_data` column.

You can use the [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-explain.html) syntax to figure out if your indexes are being used or not.

Comment: what kind of index? could you be more specific?

Comment: Just a standard btree index: `create index tbl_name_date_idx on tbl_name (date_of_data)`. If you have many distinct dates this will drastically cut down the amount of data PostGIS has to process.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work for my query.

Comment: How did it not work? No noticeable performance gain, or other problems? If you have a table column which regularly appears in a `WHERE` clause, you should always consider indexing it. It will not only help in this case if you have many distinct dates (i.e. a large value domain) but also if you have a large number of records in the table.

Comment: Is the query using the index? Can you pastebin the output of `explain analyze SELECT st_value(rast,(st_GeomFromText('POINT(30.424 -1.66)', 4326))) as val from my_table where date_of_data='2002-01-09'`?